# How to make a progressive line graph with each timestep?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
import random

MAXROWS = 20
MAXCOLS = 20

def flipCoords(row, col, limits):
    xpos = col
    ypos = row
    return (xpos, ypos)

def plot_runner_scatter(runners, limits):
    xlist = []
    ylist = []
    slist = []
    clist = []
    mlist = []
    for k in range(len(runners)):
        ylist.append(runners[k].getRow())
        xlist.append(runners[k].getCol())
        slist.append(80)
        clist.append(k)
    plt.scatter(xlist,ylist,s=slist,c=clist,marker=6,edgecolors='white')
    
def main():
    runnerNames = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    limits = [MAXROWS, MAXCOLS]
    light = True
    numRunners = 5
    runnerList = []

    for j in range(numRunners):
        runnerList.append(Runner(limits, runnerNames[j]))
        runnerList[j].row = 0
        runnerList[j].col = (MAXCOLS/numRunners)/2 + j*(MAXCOLS/numRunners)       
       
    for t in range(5):
        ax = plt.axes()
        print("### Timestep ", t, "###")

        for i in range(8):
            xlist = [2,7,12,17,4,10,16,10]
            ylist = [2,2,2,2,9,9,9,15]
            rect1width = 2
            rect1height = 2
            rect = Rectangle((xlist[i],ylist[i]), rect1width, rect1height)
            rect.set_color('k') 
            rect.zorder = 0
            ax.add_patch(rect)
        
        
        if light:
            plt.title("RUN! at timestep "+ str(t) +" first one wins")
            ax.set_facecolor("orange")
        else:
            plt.title("Beware! lights are off at timestep "+ str(t) +" watch your step")
            ax.set_facecolor("gray")
        
        for i in range(numRunners):
            if light and not runnerList[i].felloff:
                runnerList[i].run()
                for j in range(8):
                    if runnerList[i].row == (ylist[j]+1) and ((xlist[j]) < runnerList[i].col < (xlist[j] + rect1width)):
                        runnerList[i].row -= 1
                        runnerList[i].col += 1
                print(runnerList[i].name, "survives at row", runnerList[i].row, "and col", runnerList[i].col)
            elif not light and not runnerList[i].felloff:
                runnerList[i].blinded()
                for j in range(8):
                    if runnerList[i].row == (ylist[j]+1) and ((xlist[j]) < runnerList[i].col < (xlist[j] + rect1width)):
                        runnerList[i].felloff = True
                        runnerList[i].getFallen()
                    if runnerList[i].row < 0 or runnerList[i].col < 0 or runnerList[i].col > MAXCOLS:
                        runnerList[i].felloff = True
                        runnerList[i].getFallen()
                if not runnerList[i].felloff:
                    print(runnerList[i].name, "survives at row", runnerList[i].row, "and col", runnerList[i].col)
                else:
                    print(runnerList[i].name, "fell off the platform at row", runnerList[i].row, "and col", runnerList[i].col)
                
        
        if random.randint(1,4) == 1:
            light = not light
            
        for i in range(numRunners):
                    
        plot_runner_scatter(runnerList, limits)
        plt.xlabel("Columns")
        plt.ylabel("Rows")
        for i in range(numRunners):
            plt.annotate(runnerList[i].name, flipCoords(runnerList[i].getRow(), runnerList[i].getCol(), limits), color = "white")
        plt.xlim(-1,MAXCOLS)
        plt.ylim(-1,MAXROWS)
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.clf()
        
        for i in range(numRunners):
            if runnerList[i].row == 20:
                print("Runner", runnerList[i].name, "WINS THE RACE!")
                break
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is a simulation where there are runners in a platform and they have to race to the end. I want to have a line graph with 4 lines where on the y axis is the row of each runner and x axis is the time. So as the simulation goes on the row of each runner is updated with time. How can I achieve this?

[image]